# yesod installation fails.. haskell --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying out yesod tutorial from

https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart

On step no 3 `stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc`

I get an error as shown below

```
stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc                
Linking /Users/air/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 ...
yesod-bin> configure
yesod-bin> Configuring yesod-bin-1.6.0.6...
yesod-bin> build
yesod-bin> Preprocessing executable 'yesod' for yesod-bin-1.6.0.6..
yesod-bin> Building executable 'yesod' for yesod-bin-1.6.0.6..
yesod-bin> [1 of 7] Compiling AddHandler
yesod-bin> [2 of 7] Compiling Devel
yesod-bin> <command line>: can't load framework: Cocoa (not found)

--  While building package yesod-bin-1.6.0.6 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /Users/air/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I only have command line tools installed and not Xcode. Using macOS Monterey.

Please guide as to what needs to be done here to get the installation right ??

Comment: Try using a newer version of lts in the stack.yaml (entry, resolver) in your project.
See lts releases at https://www.stackage.org/
Also, you may look at https://github.com/bravit/hid-examples/issues/7